# TypeError: 'JpegImageFile' object is not iterable

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am facing an error while making a function in python error type 'JpegImageFile' object is not iterable'

please suggest how to solve this issue.

```
def image_processing(test_path, img_size=(331, 331, 3)):
    test_filenames = [i for i in (test_path)]
    images = np.zeros([img_size[0], img_size[1],3],dtype=np.uint8)
    for ix, img_dir in enumerate(tqdm(test_filenames)):
        img = load_img(img_dir, target_size=img_size)
        images[ix]=img
        del img
    print('test image data:', images.shape)
    return images 
   
X = image_processing(image, img_size)
```

The full error

```
TypeError: 'JpegImageFile' object is not iterable
Traceback:
File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamlit\script_runner.py", line 324, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "E:\Dog-120-Breeds\app_3.py", line 77, in <module>
    X = image_processing(image, img_size)
File "E:\Dog-120-Breeds\app_3.py", line 50, in image_processing
    test_filenames = [i for i in (test_path)]
```

Comment: It seems like the `test_path` argument is expected to be a list of path to images, and you're passing the function an image object.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see what you've defined outside of the one function, but looking at your variable names it seems you're passing an image into the function as `test_path` where you probably want to pass a path.

Also, if your intention with the line `test_filenames = [i for i in (test_path)]` is to get the filenames of all files under the path, you might want to look at [os.listdir()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.listdir) - your current approach will just iterate over the characters in the path.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I am trying to pass an image path in this function like `image_processing(image, img_size)` from the streamlit file uploader e.g. `file = st.file_uploader("Please upload an image", type=["jpg",'png'])`

Comment: Thanks, change the function and solve it.